# Kube-ui Not starting

Tags: kubernetes

I've been trying to set the ui up but, after many tries, I haven't been able to make it work. I am installing kubernetes in the Raspberry Pi 2 [using the Kubernetes on Arm project](https://github.com/luxas/kubernetes-on-arm).

To start the kube-ui I run the follow commands:

```
kubectl create -f addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-rc.yaml --namespace=kube-system
kubectl create -f addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-svc.yaml --namespace=kube-system
```

It starts correctyl but when I go to http://[master-ip]:8080/ui it redirects to http://[master-ip]/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui/#/dashboard/. The next json is showed:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kube-ui\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

Then I checked the status of the pod kube-ui with:

```
kubectl describe pods kube-ui --namespace=kube-system
```

And the events are:

```
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubobjectPath                           Reason          Message
  ─────────     ────────        ─────   ────                    ─────────────                           ──────          ───────
  24m           24m             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.21}  implicitly required container POD       Pulled          Container image "kubernetesonarm/pause" already present on machine
  24m           24m             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.21}  implicitly required container POD       Created         Created with docker id bb685cbaa294
  24m           24m             1       {kubelet 192.168.1.21}  implicitly required container POD       Started         Started with docker id bb685cbaa294
  24m           24m             1       {scheduler }                                                    Scheduled       Successfully assigned kube-ui-v3-k694w to 192.168.1.21
  24m           14s             147     {kubelet 192.168.1.21}  spec.containers{kube-ui}                Pulling         Pulling image "kubernetesonarm/kube-ui"
  24m           10s             147     {kubelet 192.168.1.21}  spec.containers{kube-ui}                Failed          Failed to pull image "kubernetesonarm/kube-ui": Error: image kubernetesonarm/kube-ui:latest not found
```

> Master-ip = 192.168.1.20
>
> Node-ip = 192.168.1.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line from the event stream shows the problem:

`Error: image kubernetesonarm/kube-ui:latest not found`

https://hub.docker.com/u/kubernetesonarm/ shows the list of containers that have been compiled for ARM.

Also note that the [kubernetes-on-arm](https://github.com/luxas/kubernetes-on-arm#addons) documentation says:

> kube-ui was removed, because the Kubernetes team shifted focus to
>   [dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

Comment: Thanks Robert. Guess that I haven't been clear enough with that.

Comment: @victor I'm planning to include `dashboard` later this month when it reaches beta.

Comment: FYI, I've added `dashboard` as an addon in `kubernetes-on-arm` `v0.6.5`, so now dashboard is only `kube-config enable-addon dashboard` away

Comment: This might not be relevant, but does kube-ui require kube-dns (or any other dns service) to be running?